# yaml validation against pojo/bean

Tags: json, validation, schema, yaml

I have a schema defined in yaml format. At application startup, I just need to verify that this schema has not been changed. So for that, in code I need to write a bean and validate that schema against that bean. Is this possible? It may sound strange because usually payloads are validated against schema, but I need to validate schema against a bean. Any JAVA based solution?

I was looking at [Jackson-module-jsonSchema](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jsonSchema) but it generates Schema from a bean, not validate a bean against a schema AND its json not yaml.

P.S. I can convert yaml to json if need be (if an api is available to do this in json)

Comment: In what format is the schema defined? If you want to make sure the schema matches the bean, why don't you want to schema to be generated from the bean? That way, the schema would be automatically valid for the bean.

Comment: @flyx As mentioned, its is yaml format. We need to maintain and share this schema with others. What I need to just make sure that someone has not changed the schema on the file system, thats why I want to validate it somehow (thru bean in my case)

Comment: YAML is a data serialization language and not a schema language. Your schema may be defined in YAML, but then, additional information about the structure of that format is necessary because the term *yaml format* does not map to a specific schema format.